# How can I press the Windows key with xdotool

Tags: xdotool

How can I press the start key with xdotool?

By start key, I mean the key with the Windows icon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These keys are the "Super" modifiers.

You can emit an event for the left-hand one with

```sh
xdotool key Super_L
```

(use `Super_R` for the right-hand one)

To maximize the current terminal on Ubuntu with Unity, run

```sh
xdotool key "Ctrl+Super_L+Up" > /dev/null
```

Comment: I use tilda instead of gnome -terminal

Comment: That command example obviously depends on what window manager you're using and how it's configured...

Comment: This seems to simulate Super+Shift instead for me. And weirdly pressing Super+Shift+any letter in my console prints some kind of networking/hosts list.